# MySQL ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints

He modelado varios esquemas con el Modeler del "MySQL Workbench" y hasta aquí todo genial.

El problema es que hay dos ForeingKey que no hay forma de que se inserten y me salta con el error:

> MySQL ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

y por más que miro todo lo que he encontrado:

- mirar que las tablas estén escritas iguales (mayúsculas/minúsculas),
- que las FK apunten a alguna Key (PK),
- que sean del mismo tipo y contengan las mismas propiedades, etc

y no hay forma, a priori está todo ok. ¿veis vosotros algo que se me escape?. Os pongo los CREATE de las tablas que se ven afectados por este error:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imagen`.`BOTELLA_CERVEZA` (
  `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_USUARIO` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `IMAGEN` BLOB NOT NULL,
  `ORDEN` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `NOMBRE` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `MIMETYPE` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `TAMAÑO` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `FECHA_ALTA` TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`, `ID_USUARIO`, `ORDEN`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `BOTELLA_CERVEZA_UK` (`ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` ASC, `ID_USUARIO` ASC, `ORDEN` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imagen`.`VASO_CERVEZA` (
  `ID_VASO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_USUARIO` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `IMAGEN` BLOB NOT NULL,
  `ORDEN` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `NOMBRE` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `MIMETYPE` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `TAMANYO` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `FECHA_ALTA` TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_VASO_CERVEZA`, `ID_USUARIO`, `ORDEN`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `VASO_CERVEZA_UK` (`ID_VASO_CERVEZA` ASC, `ID_USUARIO` ASC, `ORDEN` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cerveza`.`USUARIO_CERVEZA` (
  `ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_USUARIO` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_VASO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUNTUACION` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `OPINION` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `FECHA_COMPRA` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `FECHA_CONSUMO` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA`, `ID_USUARIO`, `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`),
  INDEX `USUARIO_CERVEZA_VASO_CERVEZA_IX` (`ID_USUARIO` ASC, `ID_VASO_CERVEZA` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_UK` (`ID_USUARIO` ASC, `ID_CERVEZA` ASC, `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `CERVEZA_USUARIO_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO`)
    REFERENCES `coleccion`.`USUARIO` (`ID_USUARIO`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_VASO_CERVEZA_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_VASO_CERVEZA`)
    REFERENCES `imagen`.`VASO_CERVEZA` (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_VASO_CERVEZA`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_CERVEZA_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`)
    REFERENCES `imagen`.`BOTELLA_CERVEZA` (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_CERVEZA_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_CERVEZA`)
    REFERENCES `cerveza`.`CERVEZA` (`ID_CERVEZA`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

El error da en los dos constraint de la tabla USUARIO_CERVEZA siguientes:

```
      CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_VASO_CERVEZA_FK`
        FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_VASO_CERVEZA`)
        REFERENCES `imagen`.`VASO_CERVEZA` (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_VASO_CERVEZA`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_CERVEZA_FK`
        FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`)
        REFERENCES `imagen`.`BOTELLA_CERVEZA` (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

**PRUEBA 1**

Tras leer el comentario de @Josep, he probado a dejar en USUARIO_CERVEZA:

- Como única PK "ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA"
- Como UniqueKey el conjunto de "ID_USUARIO, ID_CERVEZA, ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA".
- Como único FK la relación "ID_USUARIO y ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA", la otra relación la he eliminado para la prueba.

El resultado es el mismo error:

```
    Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cerveza`.`USUARIO_CERVEZA` (
          `ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `ID_USUARIO` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `ID_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `ID_VASO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `PUNTUACION` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `OPINION` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `FECHA_COMPRA` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          `FECHA_CONSUMO` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_UK` (`ID_USUARIO` ASC, `ID_CERVEZA` ASC, `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `CERVEZA_USUARIO_FK`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO`)
            REFERENCES `coleccion`.`USUARIO` (`ID_USUARIO`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_CERVEZA_FK`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`)
            REFERENCES `imagen`.`BOTELLA_CERVEZA` (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_CERVEZA_FK`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_CERVEZA`)
            REFERENCES `cerveza`.`CERVEZA` (`ID_CERVEZA`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

**PRUEBA 2**

He eliminado la relación de ID_USUARIO con la tabla coleccion.USUARIO y ahora solo he dejado lo siguiente:

```
    Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cerveza`.`USUARIO_CERVEZA` (
          `ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `ID_USUARIO` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `ID_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `ID_VASO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `PUNTUACION` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `OPINION` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `FECHA_COMPRA` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          `FECHA_CONSUMO` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_UK` (`ID_USUARIO` ASC, `ID_CERVEZA` ASC, `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_CERVEZA_FK`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`)
            REFERENCES `imagen`.`BOTELLA_CERVEZA` (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_CERVEZA_FK`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_CERVEZA`)
            REFERENCES `cerveza`.`CERVEZA` (`ID_CERVEZA`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

Dando el mismo error

**PRUEBA 3 Y OK**

Modificando el conjunto de PK y añadiendo UniqueKey es como he podido solucionar mi problema. Pongo el código SQL correcto para la generación de las tablas por si ayuda en la aclaración:

```
    SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imagen`.`BOTELLA_CERVEZA` (
  `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_USUARIO` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `IMAGEN` BLOB NOT NULL,
  `ORDEN` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `NOMBRE` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `MIMETYPE` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `TAMAÑO` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `FECHA_ALTA` TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`, `ID_USUARIO`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `BOTELLA_CERVEZA_UK` (`ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` ASC, `ID_USUARIO` ASC, `ORDEN` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA_UNIQUE` (`ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_USUARIO_UNIQUE` (`ID_USUARIO` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ORDEN_UNIQUE` (`ORDEN` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imagen`.`VASO_CERVEZA` (
  `ID_VASO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_USUARIO` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `IMAGEN` BLOB NOT NULL,
  `ORDEN` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `NOMBRE` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `MIMETYPE` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `TAMANYO` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `FECHA_ALTA` TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_VASO_CERVEZA`, `ID_USUARIO`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `VASO_CERVEZA_UK` (`ID_VASO_CERVEZA` ASC, `ID_USUARIO` ASC, `ORDEN` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_VASO_CERVEZA_UNIQUE` (`ID_VASO_CERVEZA` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_USUARIO_UNIQUE` (`ID_USUARIO` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ORDEN_UNIQUE` (`ORDEN` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cerveza`.`USUARIO_CERVEZA` (
  `ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_USUARIO` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_VASO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUNTUACION` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `OPINION` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `FECHA_COMPRA` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `FECHA_CONSUMO` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_UK` (`ID_USUARIO` ASC, `ID_CERVEZA` ASC, `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` ASC),
  INDEX `USUARIO_CERVEZA_VASO_CERVEZA_FK_idx` (`ID_VASO_CERVEZA` ASC, `ID_USUARIO` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `CERVEZA_USUARIO_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO`)
    REFERENCES `coleccion`.`USUARIO` (`ID_USUARIO`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_CERVEZA_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`)
    REFERENCES `imagen`.`BOTELLA_CERVEZA` (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_CERVEZA_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_CERVEZA`)
    REFERENCES `cerveza`.`CERVEZA` (`ID_CERVEZA`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_VASO_CERVEZA_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_VASO_CERVEZA` , `ID_USUARIO`)
    REFERENCES `imagen`.`VASO_CERVEZA` (`ID_VASO_CERVEZA` , `ID_USUARIO`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el error es que estas usando los mismos campos para mas de una FK y eso diría que no es correcto. Ademas debes utilizar toda la PK de la tabla foránea en la FK.

Deberías crear un campo para cada FK para así poder hacer correctamente las claves foráneas. Te da error al crear las FK `USUARIO_CERVEZA_VASO_CERVEZA_FK` y `USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_CERVEZA_FK` porque el campo ID_USUARIO ya existe en la FK creada anteriormente `CERVEZA_USUARIO_FK`.

La tabla podria quedar así (no tengo un MySQL aquí ahora pero creo que seria así si no me equivoco):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cerveza`.`USUARIO_CERVEZA` (
  `ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_USUARIO_USUARIO` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_USUARIO_BOTELLA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ORDEN_BOTELLA` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_USUARIO_VASO` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_VASO_CERVEZA` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORDEN_VASO` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PUNTUACION` TINYINT(0) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `OPINION` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `FECHA_COMPRA` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `FECHA_CONSUMO` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA`, `ID_USUARIO_USUARIO`, `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`),
  INDEX `USUARIO_CERVEZA_VASO_CERVEZA_IX` (`ID_USUARIO_USUARIO` ASC, `ID_VASO_CERVEZA` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_UK` (`ID_USUARIO_USUARIO` ASC, `ID_CERVEZA` ASC, `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `CERVEZA_USUARIO_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO_USUARIO`)
    REFERENCES `coleccion`.`USUARIO` (`ID_USUARIO`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_VASO_CERVEZA_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO_VASO` , `ID_VASO_CERVEZA`, `ORDEN_VASO`)
    REFERENCES `imagen`.`VASO_CERVEZA` (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_VASO_CERVEZA`, `ORDEN_VASO`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_BOTELLA_CERVEZA_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO_BOTELLA` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`, `ORDEN_BOTELLA`)
    REFERENCES `imagen`.`BOTELLA_CERVEZA` (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`, `ORDEN_BOTELLA`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `USUARIO_CERVEZA_CERVEZA_FK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_CERVEZA`)
    REFERENCES `cerveza`.`CERVEZA` (`ID_CERVEZA`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: Buenas y gracias @Josep por contestar. He probado algo distinto en la tabla de USUARIO_CERVEZA con lo que tú me has comentado, pero me sigue dando el mismo error y por lo tanto (si no he entendido mal) con lo que me has dicho tú no se soluciona. Edito la pregunta añadiendo la nueva prueba y me dices.
De nuevo muchas gracias por comentar.

Comment: Hola @Luis, encantado de poder ayudarte. No entiendo si has probado lo que te he comentado o solo esto que has añadido a mi respuesta. Porque en lo que me has puesto sigues utilizando el mismo campo para varios FK y las FK no estan referenciadas con las PK enteras de las otras tablas, faltarian los campos `ORDEN_VASO`

Comment: Vale, la lié con la edición de tu comentario y te pido perdón, soy nuevo aquí y aun me estoy haciendo a esta web, creo que ya lo solucionado y puesto todo como debe de estar.
He puesto nueva prueba en mi pregunta, y ya si que creo que es como tú indicas, pues más que añadir columnas he quitado para simplificar, y aun así sigue dando el error

Comment: Si, no habia entendido lo que habias hecho, yo también soy nuevo contestando, ningun problema! Pues si quieres haz la prueba y nos comentas. Y si lo solucionas puedes dar votos y marcar como respuesta correcta para que otros usuarios puedan usarlo dado el caso! Espero tus comentarios!

Comment: ya te puse la segunda prueba, y creo que ya lo he puesto como tú indicabas (eliminado relaciones y no añadiendo columnas). No se si llegas a ver la edición de la pregunta o hay que esperar a que la validen.
Aun me sigue dando el mismo error. :)

Comment: Vale, ahora viendo la última prueba que has publicado (PRUEBA 2) creo que el error sigue siendo parte de lo que he comentado al principio. Si la PK de la tabla `BOTELLA_CERVEZA` la forman los campos: `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA`, `ID_USUARIO`, `ORDEN`. Los campos que forman la FK de la tabla `USUARIO_CERVEZA` con la tabla `BOTELLA_CERVEZA` deberia incluir estos mismos campos y en tu ejemplo solo incluyes los campos: `ID_USUARIO` , `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` así que faltaria incluir el campo `ORDEN`

Comment: Vale @Josep, ahora creo que he "visto la luz" y ya se a que te referías (con toda la razón del mundo). Me vas a tener que perdonar, pero creo que te dejaré a la espera el finde y el Lunes te vuelvo a responder con otra prueba, he de mirar como me lo monto para modificar las tablas de BOTELLA_CERVEZA y VASO_CERVEZA para dejar fuera de la PK el ORDEN, pues tiene razón que siendo ORDEN de la PK no tiene lógica alguna crear las FK.
Ya te cuento y mil gracias.

Comment: Perfecto @Luis, ya me comentas el lunes pues. Me alegro que haya podido ayudarte. Si finalmente funciona puedes marcar mi respuesta como correcta y votarla. Hasta el lunes!

Comment: Buenas @Josep, no me he olvidado de ti. He probado a modificar un poco las tablas afectadasx y ahora quedan como la PRUEBA 3 de mi pregunta, y de esta manera (redoble de tambores): ¡¡YA SI QUE TIRA!! :D
Ahora haré unas pruebas de datos a ver si no he roto nada y todo va como yo espero.
En resumidas palabras, he quitado "ORDEN" de la PK y he generado una UniqueKey con la PK+ORDEN, por lo que ahora las FK afectadas no dan problemas.

Comment: Perfecto! Me alegro que te funcione! Por fin nos hemos entendido! Si te parece puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta y votarla para futuros usuarios que puedan tener la misma duda.

Answer (score 1):

Tu columna `ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA` está definida como `INT(10) NOT NULL`. Una columna sobre la que pondrás una llave foránea no puede tener la restricción `NOT NULL`.

Prueba cambiando esa restricción y añadiendo la FK a BOTELLA_CERVEZA.

Esto no resuelve el porqué la otra FK tira error.

Comment: Buenas @amenadiel, lo que indicas no es correcto (a mi ver), ya que el ID_BOTELLA_CERVEZA que indicas pertenece a la PK de esa tabla, por lo que el NOT NULL es obligatorio para una PK.
Pero gracias por comentar.

Comment: El NOT NULL es obligatorio para la PK, pero no para la FK. Si la FK siempre fuera NOT NULL no tendría sentido dejar a criterio de usuario las cláusulas  "ON DELETE" u "ON UPDATE" sino que estarían implícitas. En todo caso no encuentro evidencia de que *no se pueda* definir el campo como NOT NULL así que mi respuesta igual está mala

Comment: Gracias ami me funciono, pero es porque en la restriccion on delete, puse `SET NULL`

Answer (score 0):

una de las cosas de que se debe hacer si el campo al que deseas usar como FK no es un PK , es crearle un indice simple

ejemplo:  si tienes un campo code_pais en tabla1 y quieres hacer una FK para un campo code en tabla2 y ninguno de ellos es PK , debes crearle un indice tipo key a code en tabla2.

Luego de esto podrás hacer la referencia sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

El error ocurre por que en la tabla VASO_CERVEZA la llave primaria está creada con el orden:

PRIMARY KEY (`ID_VASO_CERVEZA`, `ID_USUARIO`, `ORDEN`) y en la clave de referencia la declaras al revés: REFERENCES `imagen`.`VASO_CERVEZA` (`ID_USUARIO` , `ID_VASO_CERVEZA`). Lo mismo ocurre con la otra restricción.

Esto pasa por que los índices son leídos SIEMPRE de izquierda a derecha. Entonces debes referenciar ese índice del siguiente modo:

REFERENCES `imagen`.`VASO_CERVEZA` (`ID_VASO_CERVEZA`, `ID_USUARIO`)